# Disable location bar in new tab

Tags: javascript, tabs, window.open

Is it possible to disable location bar when you open a new tab using:

```
window.open(url, name)
```

If I use "location=0" in the above, it opens new window, but I want to disable (not hide, just so user can't edit it) it in new tab.

Comment: Not possible.... You can only open a window open with location=no and then show the location in a span on the page - you cannot open a tab and hide the location bar

Comment: I don't think this is possible. It would also pose a security risk. Evil people could use this to keep visitors on their site.

Comment: @DBX12 - why? You can open with location off, but he wants it on and visible but disabled.

Comment: Yes, as @mplungjan said. I want the URL to be visible when I open new tab but I don't want it to be editable. I want the same behavior as when you open new window using "location=no", but only in a new tab.

Comment: As I said. Not possible at all. you cannot open a tab with different UI than other tabs